# Ansible yum module to install a list of packages AND remove any other packages

Tags: ansible, yum

I have to deal with new machines (same OS version on all) that have been previously managed manually by many different admins.

The purpose is to use Ansible to make all these machines sharing the same list of installed packages,
**AND** remove any packages not in the list that might be installed already.

Is this feasible with Ansible ?

```yaml
vars:
  - yum_rpm:
    - tcpdump
    - tmux
    - psacct

tasks:
  - name: "Install all package in our list"
    yum:
      name: "{{ yum_rpm }}"
      state: absent
      update_cache: no

  - name: "Remove any other unexpected package already installed"
    ## NO IDEA
```

Comment: you need to break your removal task into three parts(for simplicity at least). Part1, gather a list of all installed SW. part2. make a list of SW which are not in your expected package list. part3. delete the packages from the list created in part2.

Comment: with that said,  this may cause havoc to your remote host as something might be removed which is required for sane system functioning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building up on @gary lopez answer to add security and performance.

First you will need to get an actual list of **all** packages you want to see installed on your final machine, including the default ones that come with the system. I assume that list will be in var `yum_rpm`

Once you have that, the next step is to get the list of currently installed packages on the machine. To create an actual list we can reuse:

```yaml
  - name: Get installed packages
    yum:
      list: installed
    register: __yum_packages

  - name: Make installed packages a list of names
    set_fact:
      installed_packages: "{{ __yum_packages.results | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
```

From there, adding and removing is just a matter of making a difference on lists. The goal here is to avoid looping on the yum module package by package (because it is damn slow and listed as a bad practice on the module documentation page) and to make the install and remove operations in one go.

```yaml
  - name: align packages on system to expected
    yum:
      name: "{{ item.packages }}"
      state: "{{ item.state }}"
    loop:
      - packages: "{{ yum_rpm | difference(installed_packages) }}"
        state: present
      - packages: "{{ installed_packages | difference(yum_rpm) }}"
        state: absent
    when: item.packages | length > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first task you need to use `state: present`. You could try this

```
vars:
  - yum_rpm:
    - tcpdump
    - tmux
    - psacct

tasks:
  - name: "Install all package in our list"
    yum:
      name: "{{ yum_rpm }}"
      state: present
      update_cache: no

  - name: Get packages installed
    yum:
      list: installed
    register: __yum_packages

  - name: "Remove any other unexpected package already installed"
    yum:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      state: absent
    with_items: "{{ __yum_packages.results }}"
```

But I recommend you validate packages to uninstall because you could uninstall some packages required for your OS.

Comment: Isn't your last task removing all packages present on the system ? I guess it is missing a when clause. Moreover, you should avoid looping on yum module like that, especially with a large number of packages, unless you have a lot of time to loose.