# Ansible: remove packages not marked as explicitly installed (now or previously)

Tags: ansible

My inventory specifies a list of packages that should be installed on the host.
These, however are only top-level packages as I don't want to go through all the hassle of also mentioning every dependency.

Whenever that declaration in the inventory changes, **I want to remove any package not explicitly mentioned in that list - unless(!) it is a dependency of another package.**

Unfortunately, the `dnf` builtin will remove any packages that depend on the package marked as `state: absent` (even with `allowerasing: false`). My current approach builds a list of candidates for removal using the `difference` filter and then removing them like this:

```
- name: Uninstall packages not in current versions or dependencies
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    # if it's a dependency, `--test` will fail, otherwise it's okay to remove the package
    cmd: "rpm --test -e {{ item }} && rpm -e {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ candidates_for_removal }}"
```

Now that is obviously not very fast nor declarative and most certainly not elegant. In a regular script, I'd run the `candidates_for_removal` through a filter operation that only runs `rpm --test -e` and then pass the results to one `rpm -e`. I have no idea how to do this in Ansible, though...

Also, the whole process might need to undergo multiple iterations to address transitive dependencies: packages failing the `--test` command might be possible to cleanly uninstall after others have been removed.

What also bugs me a lot is that this is all very imperative. Ideally I'd like to use a mechanism that reaches the destination state in a more declarative fashion: just describe the packages that I want installed and then get rid of everything else not in that list.
(`dnf autoremove` doesn't work because the old packages were at one point marked as explicitly installed by previous versions of the inventory)

Note: I have tried the answer in [Ansible yum module to install a list of packages AND remove any other packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64392336/ansible-yum-module-to-install-a-list-of-packages-and-remove-any-other-packages) - unfortunately it cannot check whether a package is a dependency of another one, so marking it as `state: absent` will also remove packages from the list of packages marked as `state: present`.